# GeoLite2: Reader Class not recognized

Tags: php, class, geoip

I'm using PHP to retrieve the city of an IP using the GeoLite2 Free Downloadable Database.

The code I'm using is the following one:

```
function getGeoLocationFromIp()
{
    include_once('Db/Reader.php');
    include_once('Db/Reader/Decoder.php');
    include_once('Db/Reader/InvalidDatabaseException.php');
    include_once('Db/Reader/Metadata.php');
    include_once('Db/Reader/Util.php');  
    //use MaxMind\Db\Reader;
    $reader = new Reader('/sys/class/GeoLite2-City.mmdb');
    $ipData = $reader->get('xx.xx.xx.xx');
    return $ipData;
}
```

The Db folder is in the following path: "www/Admin%20Panel/Db" and so the city database "www/Admin%20Panel/sys/class/GeoLite2-City.mmdb".

As you can see I commented `use MaxMind\Db\Reader;` because it crashes my web page.
I always had a problem with Classes and for this reason I never used them but now I have to and, as feared, they don't work.

I'm working directly online so I'm not even able to see the error log.. :(

Any idea on how I can make that Class work?
Thank you all :)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the Composer autoloader as [documented in the README.md](https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB-Reader-php#example)?

Comment: because it says "PHP: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Program Files (x86)\iis express\PHP\v5.5\php.ini on line 1937 Failed loading C:\Program Files" and this what ever I ask for the version of composer or to install the dependencies :(

Comment: ok, I just fixed it and I installed the dependencies but still it crashes using use MaxMind\Db\Reader